I can hear the rear wheel spokes brushing on rear derailleur
I have relatively new Shimano Tiagra WH-RS100 700C wheels compatible with 8 to 11 speed, it has 11-32T eight speed cassette.  The bike originally came with seven speed freewheel. Although I've changed the wheels and cassette and rear shifter, I've left the original Shimano Tourney TY300 derailleur.
All works fine but while installing the new 8 speed rear shifter, I noticed that when the chain is on the biggest cog and smallest chainring, the derailleur was very close to the spokes clearing it by less than 5 mm and it works fine while on the bike stand.
But in real life testing on lowest gear ratio and steep hills, I can hear some of the rear spokes brushing the derailleur.  It only happens when the chain is on biggest cog and smallest chainring.
Can I add spacers between the cassette and freehub to increase the 5mm gap?
Should I try something else before adding spacers?
If spacers is what I need then with a 1.85 spacer I would think that the gap between the spokes and the top jokey cage would add up to 6.6mm, 4.8+1.8=6.6, Is 6.6 a reasonable gap?
Because I am guessing that when the rear wheel is under load, it flexes causing the gap between the spokes and derailleur cage to differ depending on load and flex.
By load I mean rider weight + kilos in panniers + hill steepness and forced applied on the cranks.
Here are some photos








When you fitted the cassette, were there a lot of threads engaged at the lockring or not-many?   You don't need a lot of engagement here, which supports the answers about a missing spacer.

Have you considered fitting a spoke protector ("dork disc")? If you're riding on possibly rough roads, with panniers, it seems to me a good idea to have that extra degree of safety.

Hi Andrew, I have a spoke protector but have not installed it yet. I definitely will install it at the same time I add the spacers when this arrive.

From previous comments, there may be reason to confirm that the freehub width and cassette hub match correctly, in general, for 11-speed freehubs operating a 8-10 speed cassette, a 1.85mm spacer is required on the inside (medial) side of the cassette.   It might also be the case that the rear derailleur limit is incorrectly set (with limit too close to wheel spokes), however, in this case, there would likely be obvious noise coming from the chain as it runs misaligned between derailleur and freewheel.
I would suggest the most likely cause of the problem of rear derailleur rubbing on spokes is that of a bent derailleur hanger, or less commonly, a bent derailleur cage.   The rear derailleur cage should be perpendicular to the rear wheel axle, such that the derailleur cage is no closer to wheel from top of cage to bottom of cage, both in vertical and horizontal orientation.   Visual inspection may confirm, or measurement using a derailleur hanger alignment gauge will validate whether this is a problem.
In any case, if the rear derailleur catches in the wheel spokes while riding it,  you'll either break spokes, derailleur, derailleur hanger, or bike frame.  It won't be pretty.

“In any case, if the rear derailleur catches in the wheel spokes while riding it, you'll either break spokes, derailleur, derailleur hanger, or bike frame. It won't be pretty”
Not to mention arm, leg, or other fragile body parts.

@Frank G, I must say, thank you to every ones contribution, I have fallowed all the above recommendations and although it's much better after adding 1.85mm spacer and adjusting limiting screws, I've realised that the derailleur hanger is bent.

I can only conclude that it was bent at an incident when shopping at the supermarket entrance where I left my bike locked to the outside of the rails for the shopping trolley parking bays. When I returned, I was surprised to find my bike on the ground. I don't know what happened but the shopping trolley collector, by the look on his face, gave me the impression that he was not in a good mood and decided not to ask or cause a confrontation and left it at that.  Unfortunately the bicycle locking bays in that shopping centre are too low and my lock cable is not long enough to loop back.

There were actually two things wrong.

The spacer that goes in to the freehub between the cassette and the flange was 1mm instead to 1.85mm, so now a 1.85mm has been installed.
The derailleur hanger was bent.  I've used shifter spanner on to the hanger and bent it back to the direction I think it need help and all is good.
I can only mark one answer as the one that help resolve this issue but it's really the combination of the two answers from Ted Hohl and Frank G that has fixed the issues.
Thanks again to everyone. Regards


@MindDBike glad to see it got sorted out.  The 1.0mm spacer is common as it is used on the narrower Shimano 10 speed road cassettes to fit an 8-9-10 speed freehub. Yep, the Shimano 10 speed cassette is 1mm narrower than an 8 or 9. These little tidbits of knowledge regarding freehub spacers, etc. are things we build up over time to keep us sane.

@MindDBike, you mentioned bending the RD hanger with a spanner.  Aligning these by eye is a tough thing to do. There is a tool that is used to precisely align the hanger with the drivetrain. It requires the tool and a rear wheel that is true and centered in the frame (the usual mounting position). The tool screws into where the RD would normally mount and is then used as a lever to bend the hanger and to reference the plane of the true wheel (or a consistent place on the rim) used for a reference.  Here is a link: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29552/unbending-derailleur-hanger

You did not mention if you had put any spacers on.
With an 8-11 speed compatible freehub and an 8 speed cassette, you must use a 1.85 mm spacer. This spacer is placed on the freehub before putting the cassette on.  The spacer will position the 8 speed cassette correctly and thereby also give you the proper clearance between your rear spokes and your derailleur hanger.
NOTE: you will need to adjust your High and Low (H and L) limit screws along with your index shifting after adding the spacer. The L screw (relates to the largest cog) should be turned clockwise and the H screw (relates to the smallest cog) should be turned counter clockwise to move the rear derailleur range limits toward the frame (because the cassette is now 1.85mm closer to the frame). Additionally, your index shifting cable will need to be loosened to move your eight index positions 1.85mm toward the frame as well. If you don't make these adjustments after adding the spacer, you will almost certainly shift the chain between the cassette and the spokes when shifting to the largest cog, which is a horrible place to end up.

Hi Ted, so with a 1.85 spacer I would think that the gap between the spokes and the top jokey cage would add up to 6.6mm, 4.8+1.8=6.6, Is 6.6 a reasonable gap?

@MindDBike, 6.6mm (roughly 0.25 inch) is a reasonable gap. Make sure your L limit screw is set to prevent the rear derailleur will not move past the large cog (in fact, ensure your H and L limit screws are correctly limiting the RD range to just the cassette).  You do not want your chain going between the spokes and the cassette, nor between the cassette and the frame.  If your RD cage is still contacting the spokes under flex from standing, etc. with 6mm of clearance then your wheel is flexing too much IMO.

When the I purchased the cassette at the local bicycle shop, I also purchased the tyres and tubes and I only had the wheels with me. The shop owner put a spacer between the freehub and the cassette but it appeared to me that it was just enough to lock the cassette in place without any play. I don't know the size of the current spacer on the freehub, but I will soon find out.  The new spacers have arrived.

If the LBS was at all competent (and most of them are), the spacer they put on should have been a 1.85 mm one.  If you get another one, keep it as a spare (I have a few myself). It can't hurt to measure the spacer the LBS put on.  There are spacers of other thickness out there (Shimano road cassettes include a 1.0mm spacer).  Also, as mattnz answered, you should also check your RD alignment too, as a bent RD hanger can cause your problem as well.  Besides potentially providing more clearance, your shifting performance can improve when the RD is correctly aligned.

Do not ride the bike in the large cog. It is micrometers away from very expensive and potentially crash causing disaster. If you want to ride the bike, best to set the limit screw to stop the derailleur moving to the small cog until you have it fixed.
As already said, the cassette needs a spacer. With a spacer check the derailleur hanger alignment then set the limit screw.

It is micrometers away from very expensive and potentially crash causing disaster that said, if you manage to film said crash you'll be a tik tok sensation!

@GrimmTheOpiner A rear derailleur getting stuck in the back wheel isn't usually a very impressive crash or even a crash at all (unless you're cornering at the time), though it may be fairly expensive (new RD, wheel rebuild).  Basically it locks the back wheel, you skid to a halt and hope you can unclip in time.  Very similar to a broken spoke snagging on something.  But not using the large cog is very sensible, and I'd set the limit screw to ensure you couldn't click it one time too many, even as a roadside repair

@mattnz, you are right, the gap between derailleur hanger and spokes is closer than what I think because the caliper is measuring from the outside of the spoke, so it's reading 4.8 mm but in reality it's 4.8-2=2.8 mm , taking 2 off for a 14 gage spoke. And your advice is taken, I'm not riding the biggest cog until it's sorted out.

Spacers might work, depending on the length of your hub vs your cassette.
Shimano makes a 1.85mm spacer common, but they are also available on Amazon as a multi pack of various sizes.
Check si.Shimano.com for exact specs of your equipment.
You can also try to reset the limit screw and indexing to dial it back a little as long as the shifting isn’t impacted.
